# Executing batch file with colon in it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having trouble executing the following inside a batch file

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b /a:d') DO @echo 'hello'
```

The error I receive is

```
d') was unexpected at this time.
```

It works fine when entered directly from the command line

Comment: @KenWhite The colon is **not** an issue. It is optional and does not cause the error above (which is caused by using @ instead of @@ as required inside a batch file)

Comment: @KenWhite The colon is actually specified in the DIR command syntax, Ken.  It just isn't required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a:d') DO @echo 'hello'
```

you need double **`%`** form batch file